# 1-pt compactification of graphs of power functions

Tags: compactness

I have misgivings about the graphs of power functions below.

1. Are they correct?
2. Even if correct, while the slope near ∞ for *n* +even and near 0 for *n* -even are indeed infinite, the `cusps` are a bit hard to swallow and I am not up to doing the computations. Is there some informal argument that would make it easier to accept them?

[image]

Comment: Adding details to your post would help your question get more attention. Exactly which functions are those the graphs of?

Comment: I have added the words "of power functions" but which were in the title.

Comment: You are asking if the graphs in the image are correct. What functions are they *supposed to be* the graphs of? I would imagine they are the functions given by $x$ being sent to $x^2$, $x^3$, $1/x^2$, and $1/x$ respectively. I assume you knew what they are supposed to be, and providing that information takes just burden of guessing off the reader.

Comment: Given that this is a site for mathematicians and that I had titled power functions, I thought anything more might be offending. However, no contest.

Comment: That's a reasonable thought to have for not including details. :) But yeah, this site is for mathematicians "*of any level,*" so it's definitely best to include as many details as possible. 

Also, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to say with, "... *n +even and near 0 for n -even* ... ".

Comment: I had forgotten that stackexchange uses MathJax. But, at least, I should have written something like when "n _is_ +even". To return a bit: for whatever reason, precalculus students strongly expect the graphs of $x^{+2m}$ to be like a pancake draped on the sphere. Pointing out that the draping of the plane onto the sphere treats both the $x$ and the $f(x)$ directions the same way while the graph goes "faster" in the $f(x)$ direction than in the $x$ direction does not seem to help them overcome their disbelief in having to go "forth and back".

Comment: The point of all this is to let the students consider infinity by giving them a way to visualize it. And, after all, real space is curved while planes are only a local approximation, therefore abstract.

Answer (score 1):

I think a nice way to accept those *cusps* at $\infty$ would be to compare the limits of the derivatives of those functions as $x \to \infty$ in each direction in this clever way. I imagine $f$ will have no cusp at $\infty$ if

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(f'(x) - f'(-x)\right) = 0\,.$$

We can see in the case of $f(x) = x^2$ that this limit is nonzero, so there should be a cusp, but in the case $f(x) = x^3$ the limit is zero.

And then in the case of functions like $f(x) = 1/x^2$ or $f(x) = 1/x$ that approach infinity as $x \to 0$, you can shift the discontinuity to infinity and use the same trick. So if your function $f$ has a discontinuity caused by an asymptote at $x=a$, then you could look at

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \;f'\left(\frac{1}{x-a}\right) - f'\left(-\frac{1}{x-a}\right) = 0\,.$$

Comment: Of course but that was not really my question. Students in _Pre_ calculus seem to like the idea of 1-pt compactification but are puzzled by the _cusps_. My own diffident response has been that $x^2$ goes faster than $x$ but how to explain the effect of the curvature of the sphere.

Comment: @schremmer That's exactly what I meant about your question needing more details: you didn't mention precalculus students at all, and when you use the word "*compactification*" I assumed the target audience of this question/answer would be people who had some background in topology (and so derivatives would be appropriate).

Comment: I acknowledge. Sorry and I apologize. By the way, compactifying on a torus is nice too.